# Declare Fields in groovy class Spock framework Unit test Case

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am make a Test Class for testing Employee Service , Everything is working fine , Except when i use a Field in other function it gets null.

```
 // field
 Employee employee;
 // this will be assigned to return of below 
 employee= employeeService.create(emp);
 // this(employee) gets null
```

Now what is want is to use

```
         employeeService.remove(employee.getId);
```

for delete test function ,

Below is my code . Kindly provide some suggestion

I am new to groovy.

```
package services.employee
import spock.lang.Specification
@ContextConfiguration(loader =          SpringApplicationContextLoader.class,classes = Application.class)
class EmployeeSpec extends  Specification{

  @Autowired
  EmployeeService employeeService;

Employee response = null;
 def "Check if Employee exists"(){
    setup:
    long empid = 43;

    when:
    empid > 0

    then:
    employeeService.getEmployee(empid);
 }

def "Find all Employee"(){
    setup:

    when:
    def res = employeeService.getAllEmployees();

    then:
    res.size()>0;
}

def "Insert a New Employee"(){

    setup:
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setName("Ajit Singh");
    employee.setCity("Delhi");
    employee.setAge(34);

    when:
    response = employeeService.createEmployee(employee);

    then:
    response.getName().equals("Ajit Singh");

}

def "Updating an Employee"(){


}

def "delete an Employee"(){
    setup:
    if (response.equals(null))
        println("Object is null");

      when:
      employeeService.removeEmployee(response.empID)

     then:
     def res = employeeService.find(response.empID);
     res == null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Ivans answer above works, the proper way to do this in Spock is to use the `@Shared` annotation:

`@Shared Employee response = null`

(see https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.1-rc-1/all_in_one.html#_fields)

To cite the docs why this is the proper way to do it:

> Static fields should only be used for constants. Otherwise shared fields are preferable, because their semantics with respect to sharing are more well-defined.

Comment: Well, your answer is very compelling

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use @Shared tag, variable declared with that tag is likely global variable in java or C.
I don't know what your 'createEmployee' function is returning, but that's not a problem in groovy as you can use 'def' type instead of all types.

So, you just add **@Shared def response = null**